# Fork shell script (not &)

Tags: apache, shell, fork, restart

I'm accessing a webserver via PHP. I want to update some info in the Apache configs, so I start a shell script that makes the changes. Then I want to stop and restart Apache.

Problem: as soon as I stop Apache, my process stops and my shell script, being a child process, is killed. Apache never restarts. This also happens with Apache restart.

Is there a way to fork an independent, non-child process for the shell script, so I can restart Apache?

Thx,
Mr B

Comment: What's the command? `/etc/init.d/apache2 stop` ? Maybe you can use `/etc/init.d/apache2 restart` ? PS. to whomever suggested the same with `apachectl`, no need to delete a comment because it is similar to another one.

Comment: Maybe also apachectl graceful may be a better option...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`disown`](http://www.faqs.org/docs/bashman/bashref_79.html):

> `disown [-ar] [-h] [jobspec ...]`
>
> Without options, each jobspec is removed from the table of active jobs. If the `-h' option is given, the job is not removed from the table, but is marked so that SIGHUP is not sent to the job if the shell receives a SIGHUP. If jobspec is not present, and neither the `-a' nor `-r' option is supplied, the current job is used. If no jobspec is supplied, the `-a' option means to remove or mark all jobs; the `-r' option without a jobspec argument restricts operation to running jobs.

```
./myscript.sh &
disown
```

`./myscript.sh` will continue running even if the script that started it dies.

Comment: @gpvos to me, disown feels cleaner as it avoids that SIGHUP gets sent to the process at all. nohup simply filters this signal and keeps it in the jobs table. Additionally, it does some output redirection that might not be needed. Lastly, I prefer recommending disown as it comes in handy during normal bash usage at times ... but basically yes, it's the same. And `./myscript &disown` looks like one command too ;)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [nohup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup), may fit you needs.

let's say you have a script called test.sh

```
for i in $(seq 100); do
  echo $i >> test.temp
  sleep 1;
done
```

if you run nohup ./test.sh & you can kill the shell and the process stay alive.